# Writing & showing Image OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am recording a video footage and preforming various image processing methods on each frame to obtain desired result.

Now once I get the result I am looking for i want to capture and store a particular frame on my hdd.

To do this I am using imwrite function to write the frame as a jpg. then I use imshow to display this frame in a namesWindow.

The problem is that when all the conditions are meet to store the image my program instead of storing the image, gives me a run time error.......

Here is the code:

```
for(vector<double>::iterator iter_dis = Left_Point_distance.begin(); iter_dis != Left_Point_distance.end();++iter_dis)
    {


        if(*iter_dis > 20 && center.y >= 120 && center.x >=510 && Box[0].width > Box[0].height)
        {

            char* window_Punches = "Punches";
            namedWindow(window_Punches ,1);

            Mat Hook;

            imwrite("C:\\Hook.jpg", Hook);
            imshow(window_Punches, Hook);


        }


        if(*iter_dis >20 && center.y <=60)
        {

        }

    }
```

Going through opencv tutorials This is how this how its done but in my case is not working......

Further more all the process takes place in a infinite while loop, and videoframes are stored in Mat frame; which is then displayed in a window using imshow function.

Can anybody spot what am doing wrong here....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define Mat Hook but it is empty while trying to write with imwrite()

Comment: Ok how do i grab the current frame from a video sequence store it into Mat Hook if conditions meet and save/display that frame...?

Comment: box is a bounding box, center is the center of that box and Left_Point_distance stores distance between two points......the video sequence obtained by camere is stored per frame in Mat frame at the top of the infinite while loop which is not show in this code bit

Comment: then you can use Mat frame instead of locally declared Hook

Comment: OK this works thank you a lot....wondering why would people down vote this post.... :/

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect from this code:

```
  Mat Hook;

  imwrite("C:\\Hook.jpg", Hook);
  imshow(window_Punches, Hook);
```

You create an empty matrix and use it.

Comment: Ok how do i grab the current frame from a video sequence store it into Mat Hook if conditions meet and save/display that frame...?